Accessible Menu - Tabbing in reverse direction
I'm trying to get a reverse tabbing option to work, based on this tutorial https://www.a11ywithlindsey.com/blog/create-accessible-dropdown-navigation
I have a CodePen with her code here https://codepen.io/johneemac/pen/mdZVrwM
const topLevelLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link')

topLevelLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    this.parentElement.classList.add('focus')
  })

  if (link.nextElementSibling) {
    const subMenu = link.nextElementSibling
    const subMenuLinks = subMenu.querySelectorAll('a')
    const lastLinkIndex = subMenuLinks.length - 1
    const lastLink = subMenuLinks[lastLinkIndex]

    lastLink.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      link.parentElement.classList.remove('focus')
    })
  }
}) 

Normal / Forward tabbing works fine but just cannot think how to get reverse tabbing to work and hide and select menus correctly. I have tried a few things but just cannot get the logic to work out.
Even if someone gives me some pseudo code and I'll try and work it out.
Many thanks in advance.

I don't think this approach conforms to accessibility guidelines. Having a hover-based submenu on a top-level menu item that's also a link is problematic. How will users that can neither hover over the item nor use a keyboard to navigate be able to get to the sub-items? Think iPad users or people that rely on eye-tracking assistive tech. Here's a good pattern for dropdown menus that are accessible: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubar/examples/menubar-navigation/

Many thanks for that Sean. A lot to learn!
